# Selecting users with criteria from second table

Tags: sql

I want to select users only who submitted a profile picture. I have two tables, `users` and `users_info`.

The `users` table holds basic information about the user
[image]

The `users_info` table holds information which is used in addition to the basic information
[image]

I would be able to do this using PHP to grab a bunch of users and only go with those with images, but I'd prefer doing it using a single query. How can i accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
SELECT u.id
FROM users as u
INNER JOIN users_info as ui
ON u.id = ui.user_id
WHERE profile_image is not null
```

If you aren't familiar with joins, I would recommend giving [this post](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) a read.  It is the best I've found for introducing people to the concept.

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you for the link, I'll be reading up on this

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from users t1 
inner join users_info t2 on t1.id = t2.id
where t2.profile_image is not null
```

-- note the where clause is not necessary if every user info record has a profile image.